# From this website i got evidence that masturbation is doubtful, so as a hanafi would i be sinful if i did it even if according madhab i wasnt allowed

Tags: halal-haram, quran, fiqh, sharia, sin

I would want to know if it would be sinful if one masturbates but they follow a school of thought that says its not allowed and for example in the hanafi madhab,there are certain situations where you are allowed to masturbate, so would one be sinful for masturbating even though they know that from somewhere masturbation is not haram

Comment: Does it really make a difference? The point is as a Muslim what os correct!